# Java BFS Graph Traversal - Paint onto JPanel

Tags: java, algorithm, swing, breadth-first-search

I've just implemented a BFS and DFS algorithm.

My ultimate goal is to animate the algorithm onto a JPanel...

But firstly I'd like to paint the nodes to the screen in their respective parent-child relationship:

[image]

It's coming out like this though...

[image]

What I'm trying to do is set a child's `(x,y)` = parent's `(x, y)` + 50px... like so:

`g.fillRect(x+=50, y=parentNode.getY()+50, child.getWidth(), child.getHeight());`

That way the child of the parent will always be lower and offset from the parent...

Referring the picture...

Node `B's` (x,y) will be equal to parent node `A's` (x+50, y+50)... something like that... I know eventually I will want the `x` offset to the left so it gets a nice pyramid effect under the parent...

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    g.fillRect(rootNode.getX(), rootNode.getY(), rootNode.getWidth(), rootNode.getHeight());
    paintComponent(g, rootNode);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g, Nodes parentNode) {  
    //keep generating new nodePrintList to load with new Children
    ArrayList<Nodes> nodePrintList = new ArrayList<Nodes>();    

    //base case: end of nodeList
    if (nodeList.indexOf(parentNode)==nodeList.size()-1) {
        System.out.println("\nend");
    }
    else {  
    //traverse nodeList recursively 
        nodePrintList = getChildren(parentNode);    
        //loop through and print all children of node n
        System.out.println();

        for (Nodes child : nodePrintList) {
            System.out.print("PARENT: " + parentNode.getValue() + " | x,y: " + parentNode.getX() + ", " + parentNode.getY() + "...\n CHILD: " + child.getValue() + " | x,y: " + child.getX() + ", " + child.getY());
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.fillRect(x+=50, y=parentNode.getY()+50, child.getWidth(), child.getHeight());

            paintComponent(g, child);
        }           
    }
}
```

**Any idea how I can achieve that?** Why are the children all coming out on the same tier under A? Nodes `E` and `F` should be below Node `B`

I know the recursion is working because the console output from `System.out.print("Parent: " + parentNode.getValue() + ". Child: " + child.getValue());` is:

```
PARENT: A | x,y: 180, 100...
 CHILD: B | x,y: 180, 100
PARENT: B | x,y: 205, 150...
 CHILD: E | x,y: 180, 100
PARENT: B | x,y: 205, 150...
 CHILD: F | x,y: 180, 100
PARENT: A | x,y: 180, 100...
 CHILD: C | x,y: 180, 100
PARENT: A | x,y: 180, 100...
 CHILD: D | x,y: 180, 100
PARENT: D | x,y: 205, 150...
 CHILD: G | x,y: 180, 100
end
```

Comment: add `getX()` and `getY()` to your System.out.prints

Comment: yeah, looks like something weird there.  B starts as 180, 100 then becomes 205, 150.  Children E and F are both less than parent B(2), but the same as B(1).  Don't you want `... y=child.Parent.getY()+50` in your `g.fillRect()` method?  It looks to me like `parentNode` never changes

Comment: But doesn't the output show that Parent changes with each iteration (`Parent: A`, `Parent: B`, etc)?

Comment: That's why i said it was weird.  But the issue is with the position and look at the node positions, for instance B and D.  As children, both are 180, 100, and as parents both are 205, 150.  There are only 2 levels in there, and everything is one or the other position (or both).